# Predictions in Tensorflow with a 1-hiddden layer Neural Network does not change - regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm new to TensorFlow and Neural Networks in general , i'm trying to develop a neural network that can predict a value of a property (this is on of the get started competitions on Kaggle.com ) , I know that using Neural network might not be the best model to address regression problems but i decided to give it a try .

when using a single layer neural network (no hidden layers, which is probably a linear regression) the model actually predicts values close to the actual ones , however when I add a hidden layer all the values predicted are the same of a batch of 20 input tensors :

```
   ('real', array([[ 181000.],
       [ 128900.],
       [ 161500.],
       [ 180500.],
       [ 181000.],
       [ 183900.],
       [ 122000.],
       [ 378500.],
       [ 381000.],
       [ 144000.],
       [ 260000.],
       [ 185750.],
       [ 137000.],
       [ 177000.],
       [ 139000.],
       [ 137000.],
       [ 162000.],
       [ 197900.],
       [ 237000.],
       [  68400.]]))
('prediction ', array([[ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687],
       [ 4995.10597687]]))
```

**Update :** 
 i have Noticed that values predicted are only reflecting the Biases of the output layer  , whereas the weights of both the hidden layer and output layer are not changing and always Zeros

to further check what  is going wrong , I generated the models' graphs ( once when using a hidden layer , and another time with out using a hidden layer  ) to compare the two graphs and see if there is some thing missing , unfortunately they both look correct to me but i still do not understand why the model works when there is no hidden layers and does not work when using a hidden layer

graph of a working model (no hidden layer in the middle  )  : 
[image]

graph of the not working model (with a hidden layer and an output layer )
[image]

my full code is below :

```
# coding: utf-8
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 
def loadDataFromCSV(fileName , numberOfFields , numberOfOutputFields , numberOfRecords):
    XsArray = np.ndarray([numberOfRecords ,(numberOfFields-numberOfOutputFields)] , dtype=np.float64)
    YsArray = np.ndarray([numberOfRecords ,numberOfOutputFields] , dtype=np.float64)
    fileQueue = tf.train.string_input_producer(fileName)
    defaultValues = [[0]]*numberOfFields
    decodedLine = [[None]]*numberOfFields
    reader  = tf.TextLineReader()
    key , singleLine = reader.read(fileQueue)
    decodedLine = tf.decode_csv(singleLine,record_defaults=defaultValues)
    inputFeatures = decodedLine[0:numberOfFields-numberOfOutputFields]
    outputFeatures =decodedLine[numberOfFields-numberOfOutputFields:numberOfFields]
    with tf.Session() as session : 
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        coor = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coor)
        for i in range(numberOfRecords) :
            XsArray[i,:] ,YsArray[i,:]  = session.run([inputFeatures , outputFeatures]) 
        coor.request_stop()
        coor.join(threads)
    return XsArray , YsArray
x , y =loadDataFromCSV(['/Users/mousaalsulaimi/Downloads/convertcsv.csv'] , 289 , 1, 1460)
num_steps = 10000
batch_size = 20 

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default() :
    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        inputProperties  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , shape=(batch_size ,287 ))
    with tf.name_scope('realPropertyValue') :
        outputValues = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(batch_size,1))
    with tf.name_scope('weights'):
        hidden1_w  = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([287,1000],stddev=math.sqrt(3/(287+1000)) , dtype=tf.float32))
    with tf.name_scope('baises'):
        hidden1_b = tf.Variable( tf.zeros([1000] , dtype=tf.float32) )
    with tf.name_scope('hidden_layer'):
        hidden1 =tf.matmul(inputProperties,hidden1_w) + hidden1_b
    #hidden1_relu = tf.nn.relu(hidden1)
    #hidden1_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(hidden1_relu,.5)
    with tf.name_scope('layer2_weights'):
        output_w  = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1000,1],stddev=math.sqrt(3/(1000+1)) , dtype=tf.float32))
    with tf.name_scope('layer2_baises'):
        output_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1] , dtype=tf.float32))
    with tf.name_scope('layer_2_predictions'):
        output =tf.matmul(hidden1,output_w) + output_b
    with tf.name_scope('predictions'):
        predictedValues = (output)
    loss = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(predictedValues-outputValues)))
    loss_l2 = tf.nn.l2_loss(hidden1_w)
    with tf.name_scope('minimization') :
        minimum = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(.5).minimize(loss+.004*loss_l2)

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print("Initialized")
    for step in range(num_steps):
        # Pick an offset within the training data, which has been randomized.
        # Note: we could use better randomization across epochs.
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (y.shape[0] - batch_size)
        # Generate a minibatch.
        batch_data = x[offset:(offset + batch_size), 1:]
        batch_labels = y[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        print("real" , batch_labels)
        # Prepare a dictionary telling the session where to feed the minibatch.
        # The key of the dictionary is the placeholder node of the graph to be fed,
        # and the value is the numpy array to feed to it.
        feed_dict = {inputProperties : batch_data, outputValues : batch_labels}
        _, l, predictions  , inp  = session.run([minimum, loss, predictedValues  ,inputProperties ], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        print("prediction " , predictions)
        print("loss : " , l)
        print("----------")

        print('+++++++++++')
```

also I have uploaded the datafile convertcsv.csv [here](http://job.techgatekw.com/mfiles/convertcsv.csv) in case you want to take a look .

i appreciate any help to figure out what i'm doing wrong .

thank you

Comment: I don't think any of these are the reason for the poor performance, but I noticed 3 things: First, you use `hidden1` instead of `hidden_dropout` for defining `output`, so you are essentially just doing linear regression right now because there is no activation function between the layers. Second, you probably want to add regularization for `output_w` to `loss_l2`. Finally, 32 bits is usually more than enough, so explicitly using 64 bit floats probably doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You could also experiment with initialization of the weights. If you use Xavier initialization the standard deviation should be `sqrt(3. / (in + out))`. That is `sqrt(3. / (287+1000))` for `hidden1_w` and `sqrt(3. / (1000+1))` for `output_w`.

Comment: thank you Styrke , I removed the relu activation function and the dropout because i thought they where causing the issue ,i  just returned them back , i have also tried Xavier initalization as you have suggested , but there was no change , the output layer still does not predict any thing correctly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , so i finally got what the issue was , and as expected it was the weights in the neural network , i have also thrown some preprocessing to enhance the predictions :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math
from sklearn import preprocessing

def loadDataFromCSV(fileName , numberOfFields , numberOfOutputFields , numberOfRecords):
    XsArray = np.ndarray([numberOfRecords ,(numberOfFields-numberOfOutputFields)] , dtype=np.float64)
    YsArray = np.ndarray([numberOfRecords ,numberOfOutputFields] , dtype=np.float64)
    fileQueue = tf.train.string_input_producer(fileName)
    defaultValues = [[0]]*numberOfFields
    decodedLine = [[None]]*numberOfFields
    reader  = tf.TextLineReader()
    key , singleLine = reader.read(fileQueue)
    decodedLine = tf.decode_csv(singleLine,record_defaults=defaultValues)
    inputFeatures = decodedLine[0:numberOfFields-numberOfOutputFields]
    outputFeatures =decodedLine[numberOfFields-numberOfOutputFields:numberOfFields]
    with tf.Session() as session :
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        coor = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coor)
        for i in range(numberOfRecords) :
            XsArray[i,:] ,YsArray[i,:]  = session.run([inputFeatures , outputFeatures])
        coor.request_stop()
        coor.join(threads)
    return XsArray , YsArray
x , y =loadDataFromCSV(['/Users/mousaalsulaimi/Downloads/convertcsv.csv'] , 289 , 1, 1460)
num_steps = 10000
batch_size = 20



graph = tf.Graph()
beta = .00009
with graph.as_default() : 
     keepprop = tf.placeholder( tf.float32 , shape=([1]) )
     with tf.name_scope('input'):
         inputProperties  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , shape=(None ,287 ))
     with tf.name_scope('realPropertyValue') : 
         outputValues = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,1))
     with tf.name_scope('weights'):
         hidden1_w  = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([287,2000],stddev=math.sqrt(3/(1)) , dtype=tf.float32))
     with tf.name_scope('baises'):
         hidden1_b = tf.Variable( tf.zeros([2000] , dtype=tf.float32) )
     with tf.name_scope('hidden_layer'):
         hidden1 =tf.matmul(inputProperties,hidden1_w) + hidden1_b  
         hidden1_relu = tf.nn.relu(hidden1)
         hidden1_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(hidden1_relu,keep_prob=keepprop[0])
     with tf.name_scope('layer2_weights'):
         hidden2_w  = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2000,500],stddev=math.sqrt(3/(1)) , dtype=tf.float32))
     with tf.name_scope('layer2_baises'):
         hidden2_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([500] , dtype=tf.float32))
     with tf.name_scope('layer_2'):
         hidden2 =tf.matmul(hidden1_dropout,hidden2_w) + hidden2_b
         hidden2_relu = tf.nn.relu(hidden2)
     hidden2_dropout= tf.nn.dropout(hidden2_relu,keepprop[0])
     with tf.name_scope('output_layer_weights'): 
         output_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([500,1],stddev=math.sqrt(3/(1)) , dtype=tf.float32))
     with tf.name_scope('outout_layer_baises'):
         output_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1] , dtype=tf.float32))
     with tf.name_scope('output_layer'):
         output = tf.matmul(hidden2_dropout,output_w) + output_b    
     with tf.name_scope('predictions'):
         predictedValues = tf.nn.relu(output)
     loss = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square((predictedValues)-(outputValues))))
     loss_l2 = tf.nn.l2_loss(hidden1_w) + tf.nn.l2_loss(hidden2_w) + tf.nn.l2_loss(output_w) + tf.reduce_mean(output_w) + tf.reduce_mean(hidden2_w) + tf.reduce_mean(hidden1_w)
     global_step = tf.Variable(0,trainable=False)
     start_step = .5 
     learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(start_step ,global_step , 100 , .94 , staircase=True)
     with tf.name_scope('minimization') : 
         minimum = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss+beta*loss_l2 , global_step=global_step)

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    '''writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/Users/mousaalsulaimi/Downloads/21' , graph=graph)'''
    num_steps = 1000
    batch_size = 730
    print("Initialized")
    for step in range(num_steps):
        # Pick an offset within the training data, which has been randomized.
        # Note: we could use better randomization across epochs.
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (y.shape[0] - batch_size)
            # Generate a minibatch.

        batch_data_ss = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(x[offset:(offset + batch_size), 1:])
        batch_data = batch_data_ss.transform(x[offset:(offset + batch_size), 1:])
        batch_labels = y[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        # Prepare a dictionary telling the session where to feed the minibatch.
        # The key of the dictionary is the placeholder node of the graph to be fed,
        # and the value is the numpy array to feed to it.
        feed_dict = {keepprop:[.65], inputProperties : batch_data, outputValues : batch_labels }
        _, l, predictions  , inp , w_l   = session.run([minimum, loss, predictedValues  ,inputProperties , hidden1_w   ], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        print("loss2 : " , l )
        print("loss : " , accuricy((predictions) ,( batch_labels)) )
```

below is a sample from the predictions

```
('loss : ', 0.15377927727091956)
('loss2 : ', 29109.197)
('loss : ', 0.1523804301893735)
('loss2 : ', 29114.414)
('loss : ', 0.15479254974665729)
('loss2 : ', 30617.834)
('loss : ', 0.15270011182205656)
('loss2 : ', 29519.598)
('loss : ', 0.15641723449772593)
('loss2 : ', 29307.811)
('loss : ', 0.15460120852074882)
('loss2 : ', 27985.998)
('loss : ', 0.14993038617463786)
('loss2 : ', 28811.738)
('loss : ', 0.1549284462882819)
('loss2 : ', 29157.725)
('loss : ', 0.15402833737387819)
('loss2 : ', 27079.215)
('loss : ', 0.14974744509723023)
('loss2 : ', 26622.93)
('loss : ', 0.1419577502544874
```

the predictions are not perfect but its getting somewhere , as you can see they are off by 30,000 $ for each property